# How can i print year,month as 0 in datetime less than 30day? or 1year?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

i am trying to get the month and year of this and it raises error

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime(2020, 9, 8, 19, 42, 39, 264658) - datetime.fromtimestamp(1598192097.728026)
print(x.year) or (x.month) #AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'
```

how i can get month , year as 0 ? any ideas without use exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides that *'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'* - note that time spans greater than a week are ambiguous; e.g. the number of days in a months varies.
What you could use here is [dateutil's relativdelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

timestamp = 1598192097.728026
dtobj = datetime(2020, 9, 8, 19, 42, 39, 264658)

x = relativedelta(dtobj, datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
print(x.years, x.months)
# 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

your x variable does not have an attribute year or month here x stores the difference between the two times it can only return the difference. You have performed arithmetic operation the two and x is a class date type known as date.timedelta. And as for your needs you want it to return zero years and zero months. You can convert x to string and use if statement to check for years and months.

```
     from datetime import datetime

     x = datetime(2020, 9, 8, 19, 42, 39, 264658) - 
     datetime.fromtimestamp(1598192097.728026)
     print(type(x))
     print(x)
     if 'month'  in str(x):
         if 'year' in str(x):
            print(x)
         else:
            print(f'0 years {x}')
     else:
         if 'year' in str(x):
            print(x)
         else:
            print(f' 0 years 0 months {x}')
```